# Reading the Image Content from an Exported Contact (VCARD)?

Tags: android, vcf-vcard

I exported a contact from my android phone with some software to my PC.

I exported this contact into a vcf file (its extention is vcf), here is its content:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:4.0
PRODID:ez-vcard 0.10.4
FN:Iki
PHOTO:data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQ
 EBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/
 2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQ
 EBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/wAARCABgAGADASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHgAAAgICAwEBAAAAAAAAAAAABQYE
 BwIDCAkKAAH/xABXEAACAQEEBgQGDQQOCgMAAAAEBQMGAQIUFQAHERMkJRYhMTUSNEFFUWEIIi
 MmM0RUVWVxgZHwCRc2QxgZJzJSU2R0dYSFsdHhRkdjZpSkpbTB8aGmtf/EABsBAQADAAMBAAAA
 AAAAAAAAAAACAwQBBgcI/8QAPREAAQECCAgJDQAAAAAAAAAAAAEDBgQFERchMUHwAgdRYXGBkc
 EVJTM0NVKx0eESExQjREVTZXKClaHx/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDqaDj8G7c8OaS5s/Vx7ev7vv8A
 u05z6kfYL649e1Hjaw6bJpNDTxh7BWBJVB7+A5lg9oZbUQRKjZcFjcWv7zVtc1CP9OnDOlVbVo
 3ToVQ0jJq8PGVgL1cWOnMYGFYMMXF/SJxYltvZp68dX9Jp9UOrGj6IAuSGLaLpxPTmJVpipzmR
 IYoYZbTKUuZMLDmJ2LYN+r44e3+r5gcN04K8HpMKh/NP7LZfWp9A4wHshTvwWLWUX86hue2u2m
 9FZ0e/tWuuy74F3pDqvksj/WSPqy/7S2h/X5bPVpLvfkudd8l33aqtV80262+6Oay2dVlnxToP
 9/2ac+pNZ3s837gwmm9T+ptJTeKIiAT1hLrGzyH4mqxdQggrV5vbmDb3sq+Vcp8trXTnErOaip
 1V+ob6a47MF3p5EcRSMKFhiuEFEDNOZMPjeX5hmW2zB5v15lyv0trivdenZ0p4LLopkppPMWeN
 R6GftKLmSK1XdlrsqOgk78mjr+FvX7ox+rua5/GBvn0H/e0qt8vos7bNEwj8nt7IcOa/Hcp1Wf
 c6/dB6oQwb7y/HTlv/AK++30HOr767HNDfZDgXyACN1IrTFHTwsOvaV4iy/wAbPJ6NIS065eBh
 uTX2BJQ8Q4pREiFoDjCPlWEsB/km3s7NMs17rdWNNpOdR58kV7U7zzu/sB/ZIb7fGavYzL8fwU
 dysqNggh2/25ss/Fmmf7A32Sd7281ARyX4/goulFG7mG3ybee+T/zp6H2CsZldt8OZpFwxAsuV
 uXyOfDmlBmGdaU5ZtO5SJzD+f2deZNNIdq4OEi+Txl+aSUiXeSHNLe0rGWfHuoH0Lvt0vZ4r3c
 o6UyaMq3k0VEp2Hn6sV7F7zz03fYC+yPvR3Lk1HrLl+S233OSrUO4h/ndmP43/AONDA/5OP2Qh
 knh34aTW3918IwqPiJvTZtSgssF6+r09tundbWCuoTig56eJXyX44h4pQ2lJFNYIRwxTDBChGw
 QLLjlxwm3L/LjD/ovRqhUgXgJj5l4jU8jDy7xgALBZMwD4wQruP5dhOYZZyrB5tpom0dfLGezx
 M06b2fKvxh0m/tYuuy9dub6rdVd/dy+5RxOay2w2eWzZZQ/Z6/xble/Jl67L3gXLlT6r7l/9bJ
 nNUT7n/wCj7bfq/wAtO7wdkTbFiTLicMCOXdFERuSiNyT22i8aCu7TSxO3qs0kzJYTIZhr8zS4
 MZ7qVIE0fDnbcXjOELCOWsAv7O/6on05m3dxmvvTtl75M1RKdV6OtFV9R0jfk39Ud2utcw1VGA
 R30Oq8TpHLGQAKdBNUJnB0mLsN2WhHY7F1ApYfOtN+iyzT0AlDsirxNwaZ4tuRi72EgPov7tZs
 s2iiY2xl5S/OPyPTiL7DPVP+Yv2O6eZqtYjVVVmHrKqB41bRq1gIccGoV5SED0g5ckynNl/Xaq
 a595dL4WxjNCLgea1PDu8QVLGQm1tU5PuPkuaunmX47i/+T61PbpoceJ+B3cgzJrTC4bxrf9rr
 lQxP5HnDjxwlqy5pAeK0rW8lqVV1Fl2ob5At+E92wMuWy72KQwWlyNztxgfimR2f9Rs7PXZbZp
 pFHDT3Srgft5iJbZpSMKqB2fYlBW9fX5x8um6Qq/eu+Bc3m7j/AIyWyf12dlnb6+r/ABFTTeBt
 /hdXk/H+Xo07cdLAhlP08ReMxKdfNfYSkStN4ALPOy9Rfl22Wll2/wBdP7dI0aNIO0ziEAe4fu
 7IoSJPd54R8Lg9gnX5ANlmmbLGECzXADBwy5PgiCBcdBF/VMct+q231+m3SHHdaXRb9wk8O+ZH
 2kRqyoAf+Ex1n/6fo7LbNBnDE01y7+89ps/8eT77Pt+zQfvNv7/2/wDs+yz0fj69BcNjWOSbGG
 LyRpJYN1HGAUDPD8r+O+r67fv0zu+Hcj9vfkmv9m8k6vq6v7+rZoNBAuL1pw40xiwMmbCj+6EC
 izz9nCdXV2fV/dpJDFvgi3Br5hB+7xG6IIiVwT+NW4QXaECtX8u6l/dn3bM10QHFTO08oYypOv
 cXyAB5RQjKoVo5sOGLjCyhBDQuN/GzK9uzRwVsmBgty+enMTkxxD72MgpWdBMRheLwpgRzLt7v
 817erQArMKMULMGTc3wxkRApQ5EQs8Ew5njYnUD/AJ9mz17xQ4BQ4A7nt4YItzFZL/I/st2f+t
 A0LLnhIGFM7rxVhmFKyq3ivFcX3fjuL7v7e30bdDu8ueF5fA7e238fboAZqYgyS6GMtGacHNip
 iE5QoPxUwTCd+LfleYde3Y1DA69E+7SLi+HMNfrBpfvkRcURhd/P4rYH8d5fgGOEzBsvyz+h8r
 t0ArW1QlMjzLwbhVMxhIsAsaIWhwMODK2CC4QKuGS/HdndyxV5M48ujyLM5uySTmGLyQ5Bd6KO
 OmKBn/514y6tu3zZ67Nug55TIqKmdKEXbXeQD20643gHhvl98YcreyjyUkLPYYOHg8ILsNOZYL
 xQvmH0x1927NCoIsy+G/Dfyu/7qPZFlavKh8OGKGGJi+OZfI8v7fkGzSfvrd3cv+H4dv8AGR9X
 o29XV9f1WfVpGmk/gdez7fL+PRb1dmg4ALCqk4LTJ5piL7Lcr5cOOraHbkdxjQxLSywgcvCzHK
 m23MrfiZ+km84DujkkkkxgDBykRSkNIsqghwfqNy3geE24/Z/lpMHAM9oYEGbc4fxiIWfxIrFi
 fcd9umy7J4N3d+Xdbr+r/JfX2dnZ/foADkrKld4LDbU9P78zESixZyr35g4asNwXhBMfxti4Es
 Rh1diowBv9RWMq4RFCSLPGSMRENLERHLv4JhzfE7RPvt0z3nhR3Ll/Zf3fwUd/b+Nm3Zp9ek8O
 2/4d/wAO/Jt9O2zy7dtv46/RoAtlUiM+DGtJvyXCY1YwMREatFOfCPbYGYXxbpGy+PYT/g9DaW
 lw6fHvjLQAx4yJSJSpAwFYO+IxWM4uxKCt+V7O3/HRlW3bkI0NzwPb7rr2eTyWeW319mmhsLcZ
 K2S20mQa+avIFiMHKKgnCIMF4QrYGctYcu/pP6tBLzWbB2eBW7JHWEVRHvk9wO/cwC4QVXK+Vg
 guMFY472L/ADcsqgB46ofN1TNOpOBsUqsyaWtH/d3/AAbnh3LnwX3fd27dAItIwjiwgXGri/cX
 4eICSSo6ynny+wXi7WxhtVZg5O2ltrFLBj3VwHKWmW5toNkocOG8ZfcPnkUZh45+7HrOvFezis
 ZhRPfVwQOOxfL12Vqsq5RYpyfQRGS7SlH3faXKYp+5Dt+DyZX6v5DZ2WWl+j/GNJS6GFmM4DWr
 wDB4mEXBq0MFkxBnxrxHMMd435z88HZxmlmirf1qUqRYNgGqu/fMi3okjEopWDN/NGxoP1bMu2
 WKvPGV6an1eFLY7l9Zcos+/J7lu2lb9HN9g1ecNsJyNl3cDhGPmvlJmb7dAC7RC7muzX0lSR09
 MQXiisvQoeMIw2DLxeNBZY3xT+leDt8z8q0QCkeukhsRNcr9GAsxRGFHDTCz7F1hQfXxqPgjsD
 i/OjSz0fOqpihrI+9JfgPhosA+Qr3JX08350I5guMU4vkfAnMvm/mlvzO2aaYkVFUl27NfuLaL
 sm3o+FjJrdpBvsYVg+L94+0LrxfX86h6ALy2n9bsOGzLWKnJuB/rOiIs9rgfNMZxeC6N4I7A25
 fy63muM7pVuFuatCaOma5Wx37jvWc0qCaSXbvJKXpdUPDxRnimCRduALy/mVjTxMD6U2EpnVSX
 Lt/DLaTYX8URhY+lrSCcxfiuEKwfRVlx3zsv9Xe3VoButmDEeaap4XAFzAL5Yl9Ly1QaqhYBlO
 DCy82SUPTdQG5jhBF9i+xm0VNVQdluUq7e9ALLh8OO7bcvkyE3/hdsmF227PWF2bfxt0JBjX5p
 rl+98H1/j0fjs27dKKFDGjKPJuNa4vwkAJkyuMhXrvnnDXh5Pi7CxLHnGnMej36Qcra8YfnDZn
 mbTNDZB1zLyUIbKsAw8LlcUhFB67jmsPChhiFdLc8zA3qUicwXM1dmamH25tnDJpoIYFS6dyDn
 W1C3KxyS4St1dNQ18ziUsPWBQZVb28YKHaJlPvqpzJe6ebd6Zr9F6BBdU8JBwzJ9DRBlwM+oCs
 Ojo1ojnmIrD9IcWX04ZLzQWJxZjBuuYrGipq1wDfvhar0gD03ckXwmtXdWG2ZMPTiGMP8APcqn
 Dp/FGBl21Cp6cMmBtV4H/WAxyuqlTXAN827r0JMEripGE/h1CwGvxJnCZ1GOm1oU2CYO4GMDDK
 p7Ja4pteE9XAh/pAuzSqlTXm6dtS+Zc0EyMLqPpgM99NBYwhAqQUgU+MeqNY0DWHGYyyzo8X04
 y+mDubFr7OjqxXlSnAZP3arytkD1XoRczv4mpMZUEWx8QPXleQQTEYUy3FU8IbVTK2mPGy7VK9
 czsytVgMn7szXTBPQZ6UW5CBUjCcmSwjFEOHNeVHBxhQeLwgbrWMywXinzm19KfK+6rP0XVQku
 3gL55LR3fXtLH0Ubyp68eAzMDOMLxal1VTJfYD80r+6lXdGU5PoBTy1s4dMrnGa3AJjACCoiKp
 oilx1QeT240sWwsIHLkpy7Ni6fzBjlea4OxunbNMtta6Hil+s4YPwjaz318cphLEQRTiEGDDh4
 wwSwvBVWsxoOOUh7fnVVUh6hwps7aXpO7R9+k3mZDU3RcMMgq9pEYrl1yKp4cGhDMUlNqeCBZL
 88XPBO77Witq1xgCjvhlzQqQ8qBfeGhPDjVrR31PyyyBudd0x0w5hRjjCiFm0rxp2BwnIMs2te
 PzjLMtV6CllyS/cWK0qKqh7owaqodVw2YYdYrkeVQ0O31QGChuFIoglh3GnZGX3fmdmaWGAVfb
 ldvKrA/TBkCyFhPrzU/DMTEQVKOwqNpjg84KDykoRSa8y80FiC2zC1fmavtRZPZ75feunz1oqU
 3ctWV4GkayAMMfGRrLFnBhqDzSKI21nUOyYcxeFqV+YZY0VZUXm+UtPeva0anFdGCwz3w6qjJh
 peIcCo43FZauUbUKoMhMwitsJ0Vy5KcxeF08vy9izVtc2Ms5Tk+3pQLiNUBjsea4BUOsXV2vvo
 yhyqpHIrKsqcap2BgppomLsCqpb3iCIJUGXscrVZUGfZppQssO0T08TU9DzOCac3ogf57qyavH
 DAPg6hKyl0CyYZEuBUl1B0gsZtGqpqnPUOc0T5o2sFQ6zHC8oCY++ZfVMIk5QG71l6kTmr4cx6
 GnU4QQ3o2v6K1Fa3EzaoMzzXpVgKRTqeZWttJ8NTVzg9+AycX1ob5eLHUFQPtTcB9YJ8KGYX0e
 ES5avzzi+78sVqmqqzN82pjMlarQZy0gKNxwYzK/WFQQktABwIo0esFpYj5xk5inKW3Lca8wKk
 TKWGWK7WuMPzlS1zJo10e7qcwWS/NfqqqCbcAQLFiIUO44xpsUlCYKleynQRMv6urKu9802q9K
 fFqTWLhxr99k4Cy8+fdGEaqhXhD5enxifmwlF1wz7yzZSw2U70XatejZ+TqMnZK1SttV1VVp91
 aZDNubnWKUvaam68VblgbjMJhMbVWYWgrjrVPSxfzXxM/uvMs1VjQPIUky2wlwS7rhkGQVuok7
 yiCoMHjGmMEwgYVKrag5cC2Ur+Y5oqyoPN3PdrRrbPLaHw4u5cZD3CZPcgI+hr462HhTPGywju
 dA47yrsr+aPpXRAgZNYSL9xgwMmWosRKUOHq51jTzmW5WGHwjYJ4yXuvG7WHLs0zVttydta4pt
 poIbGzDAmDAN6tFuGSpz4hiKI18PZ8wT5PTZYvSFI8ZZKjY9Hv9HcqVcZ0ucZp0kaNWgFmxuWt
 26YTfM2Bx8fEORQdUQH5eGKEG2Ft47jTmJ2LYKbFyzuowCzKWeW5q0jJqicGb6/O4k3IYA55X7
 kteI57B8UYHwmdH7Md9H+vunmWiZcv744xrYS9JSYVPuiVcuu7rAwuM7pCOy805iCpy/MF3nUz
 zo4ZZU0IJ5k8hUyGFlWl9bIVaVhyKX1yAHcE0wYm2t6nO/3eL852cpNzfZZYy5oBTbNoHHe8OZ
 PrA3JmTuRAw33sg9/DjGqfF8IFQ/Jcvsqzu/vXbn+cKfe206Lw17ACK6YMKh1kXL8svFDkVR7J
 afsaBuBOLNpWzsxbZh1eQMBR1Zlys7dplwfdDPqGmGFqqNCQrlpzovQZDzjBU7gQXNunNSL8Cu
 PVVCvy9csypq1qRC32K8taNdK+eUDUjBfCtc0YudQr4qgwuSUbRqrxwpwYIUpU1PriZU+E8YnC
 ZhmDJY0VNeki+1wpV++i1YKmfwsvbVLbbpk1jm5zsMXBgUw8ahyREK4iJNY2viA6ZgHzgTCFpa
 HZVAFSuOzb90Bc0yrKsBk9jSxkrVKysLRkU3VADU3UEJ8grg+whpVGuRUqhITtMnLxbY2lej5p
 zGqu6V7FnmrWlffcnUtE/XpJH1YwlC8yMDGmIxER9lNrygDph8LykWyoTTmdQY6ncIpYZgu6Lt
 c1pukm/K7VvNF67qHo9XgBqPp6lqYADFHAFXxq31kGHDfB1IILhEtVU2vNBZPBMwbr8s5rwGcb
 E61Wq0F2HySad6jtVC1bCGtx6qkJg48w3plUPsqydMGrM6QvlLfI2W05ciKLzZhtV9Yfe3nXRV
 V3tTJEbhlSqT2PZcI6EcWKQOqEOBsTp3xjik82tS0ravCBzzo8w6+6mplvemWq2rUwnoGs0Y6c
 YesKev5XKuilxiHWOdjE4ZScsQXjtcXfnCVDm1QMc0zXOEOcKMnptoqqg3T9D1grvDWX6np825
 aKPK0xCavJ5zKhzTOGpQhbrXEywNKsbA1K9TR/NMqVBnp82ydllSsVNLNe4lGL6MldZ3cJ1RgV
 PIAO0ibtacVztZh8KZhCsXa8WsMCu6PB+rKqbP7r68rzo/oTduqnCp5qfJDYR0+KKZSdJCKsbg
 3wadSKIWFVTKzA8IXT6lf5qa28n/RvKmmtXqzcQjssfWBEx5BS8qIgArWNBBDgysYYLhHWtSpO
 8eLynLsryrgLLM0y1WqsartB37scMMNaVJcuDikAYiTIXh0w9oqfKc3a1OjqRgacudiNmGYfTB
 /zar0Fnqr+SfQhpIzFQwF+h7i0iJOKmXx0b7vavcZOYXgywnmX2AscobWqWGWZXa1wFvNOjbTN
 NJzCob12+eM4p/cyYjId1qlrKoyFi/NE+LFLyWqvkKkv5r68A3ym1Otypobho/wpMZbVDglrvS
 N68kV0HmuIMFTh4rF9FfNwKkTy7e35sV6Siqdd4yYmHWFWAYVksEoquMWg5wQ8GrDDwomyh8w+
 VsG3M+9TOT5WnypUrEmVn0puNE1TXx2VwCMoy5CHiJZY49XNZHQZeGrxheEbBcBjsfi8p70zXu
 jmji3QKLVzVlCYHC035g8qcUvEaltaEEEOMVmGFiliGvONOY4T+ytuUOMzcMlejNcUspL9+Tp5
 Um5XikAFRxC0btxGV4PNC/er49xfSD5qzXzTan5VpujUnq5hiT6/eFXI5R4pR2EVGwQGW+J2iF
 4KlVuzMTvm716CJ//Z
TEL;TYPE=mobile:+62 852-4285-7809
TEL;TYPE=mobile:+62 852-4285-7809
TEL;TYPE=mobile:+6285242857809
ADR:;;;;;;
NOTE:
END:VCARD
```

I need to understand the meaning of photo location in the script above.

Is it possible to convert it into a raw image file (like jpeg or png)? What software can be used for that purpose?

Comment: Just decode the image data from text to binary, using the Base64 encoding. Use the decoded data to fill a bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

For this simply what you need is to get the data into a bitmap or a byte array. you can do a split and read the key value of "PHOTO".

```
String encodedDataString = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxQSEhUUEhQUFRQVFBQUFBQXFxQWGBQWFxUWFhQXFRUYHSggGBwlHBQUITEhJSkrLi4uFx8zODMsNygtLisBCgoKDg0OGxAQGywmHyQsLCwsLC4sLywsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwvLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLP/AABEIAJcBTgMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAbAAACAwEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAACAwABBAUGB//EAEUQAAEDAgIGBwQHBwMDBQAAAAEAAhEDIRIxBEFRcYGRBSJhobHB0RMykvAGFBVCUuHxU1RicoKT0jOiskNE4hYjNGNz/8QAGwEAAwEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgf/xAAwEQACAgECBAIKAwEBAQAAAAAAAQIRAxIhBDFBURNhBRQiQoGRobHh8FJx0TLxFf/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8A5+FSEzArwL64+A3FwpCZgVhiA3FwpCbgUwJC3FwpCaGK8CLDcVCmFO9mrDEWFMThUhPwK/ZosNLM8K8Kf7NTAixaWIwqQnezU9mixUxMKQm4FMKLEKhSE3AqLEBYuFITMKmFAWLhVCZhUhAWLhSEyFITDULhSEcKYUBYuFITIUhA7FQpCZCkICxcKoTYVQgdi4VQmwqhFhYuFUJkKQmOxUKQmQqhA7FwpCZCqEDs2imrwJ4YrwLDUb6DPgRexT8CvCjUGkz+zUFNaMCvAjULSZ8CsU0/2aL2aNQtJnwKYFowK8CVhRnwKYFpwKYEWKjNgV4FowKYEWFGbApgWksVYE9RLRmwKYFowKYE7JaM2BTAtGFTAiyaM2BTAtBaqwJ2KjNgQli1FiEtTslozlirCtGBUWJ2TRnwqQnFiosRYhMK8KZhVYUxWLhSEyFUICxeFVhTYVQgdi4VQmQpCB2KhSEyFUIHYvCpCZCqEx2LhSEakICzrYFYYnhivAuTUeroEBivAnhiZTAGYSchrHboy4FeBavZhCKaNQpYmhGBXgT8CsMRqJ0Gf2avAtGBXgRqDwzP7NTAtGBTAjUGgz4FWBacCrAjUT4ZnwKYFowKixPUS4GfAqLFowqFidkuBmLFWBacCrCiyXAzlirAtGBUWp2ToMxYhLFpLUJanZLgZ8KosWgtQlqqyHERhVFqeWocCdk6RGFVhT8CotTsnSILUJanlqohOydIjCqLE+EJaixaRJaqhOIQkJ2FCoVQmkICEBTAhSEUKoTACFCiVIGd8BFC7jaDPwN5JjWN1NaOAXz79JR6RZ9svRUuskcABG1h2Fd9pRY1D9Jdo/X8Fr0Susvp+Tgig78LuRRjRHn7ruRXcxKYlD9JS6RKXoqHWTOP9Qf+HvHqiHR79neF1sSvEpfpHJ2X78S16Lw939P8OWOjX/w8/wAlf2a7a3v9F0wVaj/6GXyLXozB5/M5zOjdp5eq0N0Rn4fFagFMKxnxeWfOXy2NsfBYIcor47/cynRGH7vefVKqdGg5EjfB7wt2FTAiPFZY8pP7/cc+DwT5wXw2+xx6mgvGqd1+7NZ3MIzEb13nMKXUg2cJ3rsx+kpe8vkcGX0RB/8ADr+zhwhIXSq9Hzdh/pPkVifRcM2kcCvSxcRDIrizyM3B5MTqS/wTCqERVLazlcAYVQiUTsnQLIVEIyhJTslwAIQlMKAlVZm4AFDCMoSnZDiAUJRkoSU7J0oFUVZKolOydJUKiFZcqxJi0gkISERKElMWkEhUQrJVEpi0lEICFZchLkxOKKKEqFyEuVENHt/tOl+0bzRt6To5e1ZzAXlfsvRv3al8BUd0Voxz0alyPHWvifZ8z9LuXkerPSVEf9Wn8bfVWelaH7al/cZ6ryrejtGH/b0tvuj17Ef1LR/3el8LT4lHs+Y7l5Hp/tWh+2o7/aM9VX2zo/7xRv8A/Yz1XmXaDo5/7aiT/I35CL6nQ/Y0+A/NHs+YW/I9OOlaH7ej/cZ6qvtfR/29H+4z1XmjoVCP9Cl8DUf1Wh+wo/22+iW3mFvyPSDpah+2pfG31Rt6TonKrT+NvqvKnQ9Gn/42j21+ypf4ohQofu+j/wBmj/iil5hqfkep+06P7an8bPVczprpprQPZVGnC19QltRky0EAYYOMAukiQZDQuSaND930f+zS/wAUDmMAOCjRaTAPUYMQmYMN2hp/pTSXZhr/AKOp9B+nqdbQ6Ti6m2xEYos1zmgw4z9069m0L0P1ymfvs+JvqvGaLo9Km1rG0qYDRA/9thjsktJ4p8t/Zs+Bv+KnT5Dc9+hu6K+k7aukvouLmRVe1nVacQpscXAAXuWYsRtDotYnv+2B1tPELxtCmGuqOLWu9pEjC2xDQ2xOQIaBhy5rQHDLAI7GNHgFco9kOU43s+323+p1ulOlmUS6YAFPFiHWGIuDWAtBmM5juWjR+lWOcxocDjbII3Yh2gRK8+WDU2NXutjiNf5qm9HAYAKYhplvVEk4S2ZB7Sd4CXhyfRi8WCPTdI16dNjn1CMLWue4uAMNaJcZPYsVE0KrntAjBhlwJaDInqzYxrjJc86Lb/SHwhU3RbnqNBMTIGoQO5bQjmj/AM2c+SXDyXt0zT0hSo0gCahAc9lMThd1nuDWixGsrNVa0YsNWm4MDy8zAbgLg/ETYEYXa9RQV9BDgA9rCMTT7ozBDmnmAeCJnR15Apg3vhGsydWsyuuGXiorfc4pYOCl5f0xlHo+o8EtAMEtzzjZ2JGk6O+mQHjDOWKwO2CJm0n0TqeiFgMEQSTGydkiw7N6GtoXtAMeEhr2OAM+80lzXW2Fq3Wfiqb0r9+JzvheCc1HU/34GJtQENcHsLXjqwZnPI5EWUpEujDDpEjCZBtisddkejdFspvc8M95rRAg3DqrteX+q/4jqVudSYA0te2AALbBYdoMQdolbY8ud84rr+/Ax4jhuFVaZNcvlv8AfbyXxEtBc9tNol75wsloJjOMRGUi2aVjtOqJnVG2UmpQDjTNI1WmnLWup4g6DGLrYT1oGratlKlTM4mETImWCZAkkPew5NF75DYtvEzLnFGHqvDOqk+pnL0Jcm161NonqkDbEnbYVidmpKeDhDg+heDhBMiduK3eV1RdnmzxaXzBLkONKdXdP3OAkc5IKH279rRefdZPMha6WczlFdRpeqNRKo6Q9plpbOXuMjlhhMZp1Vsw+JziBPABGmQKUOrfy/JRqITUVV9MqPjE8ujIEzG6yztc5psQNVs79qpRfUTa6MeXoHVO1VT0hzRAFP8At0Xd7mko2dL1mWa4AXOECkAJ7A1JqXRL9+A4xg+bfy/Io1RtHMITVG0cwppGn1qlnOceyLdwWgdP6SGCmKtTC2wAwtN+2Ae9Htdl8/wUsUL5v5fky+1b+JvMI6fW93rRsv4LPU0t7iSRfWQBPHDmhOlmAMTg3OIdE7YTd0JY1e9noBQfscrbQdsPf6LtBXgC8X1PEfTevZTks0Jx1gcT6LRS6LJzqNHFx8l0MIRNCHwmLsNcbksxfZIH/VHCSe8hG3opmurww/8AkVrIUwIXC4xPjMhnHRLNbx8J80xvRNLW8ncP/Eo8A7VDS+fkp+rYxet5O33Db0do4zc/dbzaoND0b+Pm26WSNo5/qlVqloseZ74Cn1bGWuKzPoaxQ0cWg9/5QpVZo+oAby7ZvXGOjt3cSFBozdp+I+qv1XF3ZPrWZdEdbozR6QpgVcD363AloP8ASDAWxpotMikzn/kvNmgBeX8yR4oDQcTADyf5ZNtyfqmO+f1f+ifF5ey+SPQUS1r3PDZJOKCQQLRYak77SjINHCPBecq9H1mjEWuAORgR2A3smu6PqAAvIAOUAkzE5WtbOYVeBi7oh8RxEn1OxW0/FMltxHfO1UdNbrI/3eq4o0Zt5rNtn1TnlFxnM5EhG7o9vVOMunU1gd4a98KlDGuv3Jc8z5r7HUdpTNo5lAdKZtK5o0Sk0kvL4B+7hFtsG45JmiaHoz5cXVR2OfTAz1k/lkquK7mTxyfRGp2mM2kf0n0SXaWzU8/CfRAadEO9ymW//q6TxNQeajdKbTBw0KThNy4teYOqDUkxtACakuif0JeF9Wvr/gmrpOx/eQkjTHzAfc5AXJXVqdIMqEEupUrC7KJLhsAjXlshbdG+kFKizqPe917CmxpOoXchzlW0f35AseNPea/ficBjtJJgNqEzEezOYzGWpdMaETDXUKxcRJLqYBGy+Jg75Wk/TOoR/puPbiY3uuOaTV+lNZ3/AEm/1OmfhaO5S45pe6l8S/G4aG+q/g/ycvpLSzhFOq1zKbSQ1pIkbbYp8QuM11En728yJ8Vo6Rcari5zGiTMAkgbpKyDR4+6D8711YsOlczzuI42MnVX/YL8J91o5z4JQN/dJ4nwIKf7I/gHzwS30Y+6OMLpSo4ZZdT3SDa8bCPnYAhq6QBqO8z6SlOAGbQfnehOGPdFu2EyVBX1HN0sbRxnzV/WRtHesrMOpoG+SikHO3ZfzS1DeOI59Zu3wVY5+fySywbeB9Ch9mDaAR89idgooM1WjOeMeSp9Ru3uPjCplEDds1eKV7ITkd8keaW5SUQm1hkQeRvzUDx/EOAjxVBg2HiVRA28E9yqXQhqgHX/ALfNCNJaTF/NXUFsjxj0WcsGrxd5FS3RcYxZ741h8wlv0sbWjv8ANeZGkuNyTwA8moy8657ZNt1vRcXhs9pyiehHSLNbhyVHpimNc8F5z2jNg58dQVjSm3GE77mO4QjwwU1XI756cbqCo9ME5ADeT/iuC3SIyB4hwt8So6WdrvnbPqqWEh5l0O79qn9LomdL9nP9V552kkm2I6rAHyso1zh+Ibw31lPwbF6xFcz0D+mjsPPyhZqnSJOUDgZ8FzmVOO3Ib4sV3ehvo3U0puNuGnTkgOe89aM8IAuNWpZyxxgrkaQzObqBlZ0tUb7rgBuYJ/2lVV6SqOvicTnJaDfx7l3qf0GqAkGtTDbZCZ3hZf8A0hVDzdgaMnYiS69iGgeJUKeDuims3WzinpGp+IzEWGGO4KxpFTUe2+vfNiu+z6Lk29q4E5AsME6/veS6egfQZudarUJnJvVHGZnkE5ZsEVv9iFDPJ+z9zyLdIqxZ3ZZjIHEWS216pcS2pDjmIG73cu5fQq+l6NRYabcJDc2OLTukZnUvn3Tf0le55borWsbJBdGG+XVAy4gox5FP3ScylD3y3VawPWe4ntgTFhHcrdpdYgtLjGwho8j4rzD9Gc4y+oXE5zLjzKbSBGbnOG+43Oz5yuiOnt9DinKf8mehp1HjNrTaJLWO7yCnN06rGFtQtFrDCPBswuLRrFuVSpHb1h3rbT0t/wDA7kDHAq9EX0Rj42Re8xrmuJlxe7eCfIDvUxgbd4A8Lpra2XVknO1mmPxRdNv2E7Y/S2SdkNW92ZzXcNZ+Ez4+Ss1XkZg9nqDCa6dZAz1iOBJEK2PBzcCD92QZ3bQkCMznvmIG60+IV+1OU88PqtbtHaYtPHxlIqaFGviSOFpRaBx6szuntI7IP/ElBi2HmfWFp+qDbfw4nLmEt1ESBcXjjvBKtMxkhMic7/0oC8bb5XEDcmuiYGIneShka79keQTItCnC3vbiRbhCED+Ic+cLQ2icwO4+KRUfGo8CT5pqS7iqXYjqY7PGUBo7DZRzDtPrzKUaTheRxM/kjUNRfcYKe0gd08IulvwjWeACWaW1o4W5RZGypAiXCNv5oUl1L0sjn0z95vd6Ko2dwy70NRgP3cWqwaO8pLmQ6AwgbfnzRZSj5jXuI+67l5SlPqHWw/PIoMAJz3y7ZsV1Ra7oGyxCWotRQTXxYhw7esedygcROZHd5IX0wRMNsP4vzlRtNoEvBM5XKVstJG40XRMEbxHMKNo9o4AJP1+9nmP5bfE4SnfXJE9U/CPF11KgjreWXKwXteBF41gtaRG4hUx4NsLb6wHDlIKD7QfqED+Zve0C3NFR059+sIFzDZjiTbiqoi0ubGEt1nhAnvEo/rJGTCd0j/jAQfaBz6xjUMIJPJLZptW+Euvrd5AI3JbibhpJgYqTADqc+CR2AKUektEacPs3VqpIAY1xYwDWXVDmdgC59L2rz1sRGwQ0HfGpPoM9mQ8OAcPdAFtc3Nj3gyeMSjtzocZx1f8AN/I9f0N0t7NrvZ0WBxYQBBa6oBJgF17xkdcbhl6M+ljnvLatV1Mmeo4UxTb1oGHCJcTe7iPdsCvK1+kHF7XgzhjODDsp7ZGu2vsVaRULyHYy0xE7NkGxhcTxqTs7I8Qo+yfStK6TbT6wljQLvIcGTexAIOrWsnQH0uNZrmy0OJOokBuQJlx74XhNG0iqJa+o5zHCMUh5GrN0GIOVlj0nQzj9o5wJOZMzl+LPvUPF0o0Wfqme66T+ldak7qQbiLWNrkZCey/BJd9PajmQ+7ry2C0chnq1n15bNEa9jXA3i4JLp3EC3GFhqaO0fh7/AJCuMIXujOeTIlszXpnSjagk2J2Dy/Nc57ZyIO4HvTG09ia0fNl3QjFLY8zJKTe5lbR+R+ab9X1/r3LSLa47PVGx38p3R5SrszpiKdPf89psj9lH4DruR+icHjW2/YT6o8Y2dpvKWolxfMXTaRkLdhafJEKrwJjLeOW1A8tzMgdsR3gq2OGpzsv4e689yB0y21HCItfMeYhEKzpJxZ6yBusBHilvqkZOO4gjxcFHaSQLhnMz3SEml2GnLoxtapB6uInbt4au/IK3VDbFOVtfC6yDSBmYG7EZ3W80X1ozbLtDh5JUkDc5G01JuN0CM9pkwEprjOe3OCfG6T9ZeZAwxE3DieazOqPm4/2x4otITjJmotI90Nk5mPVRtPDfCM9WXj5oHVS6AAeTfLJL9oQL5zlaTzsp8SPmPwp9GjU2qTIuBsmD3TKRXZBJ2nPOY3cEsVTrHbqEbxqR4ichvBnLWnFxfIUta2YYAw5tnaZB7Isl02Z2ueIPEKnPES4ARqFp5JUtOt415jvRp3uw1bVX78AiIPvAHVY+IS6z4F4IEwcuU5ptSm6DDmlo5ngQs4e/Iidwy77Kk0OgQwEdWAeUclYYRmZ7/KUTSNgHM+HkhcxoGK2eUOHMEWRaQU2DVadU/EPVCQQLB3z2mFbw07OBarJEZkdpkeKaYcgA2bujttt3BUaRmxwjtB8QUbQSTDtW0nwS3hw+9PBtuYCL8it+6M+CR7ojK7gO4SVop0GgAuEDbc9xN0Ta7veLWNjeY7JI8lKunvPukN2GLndNzvgpt7HQlbqw6fR4JmCBqkRO6/ktf1VgsST8xwXG0ys91jUcGm0N+/nm/VuCttVzQcssoLr7TiCjW2ytKpHQq9IUWHAHMBy6rXPIPaYgc1PtVoAsXHg3LW7WsVHSBAgDO5IaL7LDs8E8UgTAGewR27dhHNQ5bcx9dkPo1H1ZJOFv4Bab/eOxbm0I3nhPZZc3o5zWlwBnFvJMfJXRbWkEHU6x2CJXFn1m+LSzFW0W5OrO8HWJU0yhDoblAI15p9V0kAza3b3ZrH7adeVu0R2HNPB5k5l2JTe28yDqyI7ZlOD5EWg21/okuM5gO7fm6gcBrDdUEx45LpcX0ZjGS6otrsAjDAnMSeAIMLWyoxxGrme3elUyCLkHYRHjrRUtGkyI4AWUNSfM1TS2RodTjIAd6HEiLnDOeSIOccpEbcJJ8FUXL+RElD+IrFu+eChIOqe/lIV+1Is4a7yE5tEG4g9kK7mZ6Yf0IDBsjwQmRqPbEosDhJiRqgzHAJlJhORvsNibaozRKUo7sUYxlshIrDW07xNuVkQZORnskT3wgry09aW72yO8W7kTC05sa7YW+ZGXGUvFh7w/CyJ+yQy3W4dhBI9OaUa+Hs2534AEdyntYNi7PKAY3p/tS7Mt4dU8REFWvJmcr6r9+ooVWHWe33fGZV4BkCOIB8UD6L/4d56vK8IX0iMyBxJHOCO9UZ12YRoHaeAI8CoJGeIcz3wqa0gGHW2gjPgbKNDh70xuaZ4i6Tm1zQeHfUZSqEZGJtk78pTWOgyRIy96Z4G/LJLD2jIncL+cpTagmxve1wlaYU4j3gB1g4zt1WnUlVWnMGRG13mbqB8Gw43tzbdTHBvbXJw37OqZHcpuPcdPsDScdZjsM+EKzFjiHf8AoEQ01s+7FsnX8SVnqtBvETlaB4R3q05diWo/v/hoLZkTE8UBDp945ZZAX1RwSGgCwjg4DuutFJs5Ejs/QK6iTclyFOJE533n/kFALe6eEfkmGodojtEeMFBjPPWDHj4p7cg3KdXOsHLY+O6QkEgn3eLZy4LQGkbd8h/eJVNJ1kHhHmhRHqMzwDrbGwkE9/qrZMQCYnVJ8E2uwawN+tZNI0BhjqjfICmUPJMuEk+rQVPo91T3jjjVkCdUrTVY5v3GxtsZ1XuI+bKKJSdM3W8bZna/EbtiNcyZ7k5+jEQSMIdfMTAOwW7goonzqyG6uhwYANhjM3sTfIWyCjpLRhLtc5QIyjWooopWVboChTEAmZdOvXrIAsq0mm5omSQMyDHFRRTNbjg7RVKqTmesMna9x+SoylItn88FFE9EdNiU5OVA0asOLX5tG+PmFppFjx94do1bxN1FFCd8zSq5F1NGc28iM5vw7U2iXRMjfH5BRRPkhtWxrtKc3XLdZMEciJ8UTaw2luuBrv2BRRDlSsWncA6SJPXJ7CDvPZlKaykHZkZTlGedwJ2KlFljyOU9LLnjUY2hYols4nHLqkajkMQvbdtWY6Q7FDyPGRE9iiic8sovYUcMJLcZ9otgADxg8DKSdIbJJbBGy3gYUUXRBKa3RzSuL2YWCm6Ze5picp8BbmhGhBvWa8kDO0W4lUoo0xtqkW5SpOw6DpdYujDYSL75hGKjri1pizYEbZ17lFEpwUY2hQm5yplMc8yScvvdu5NNT8WWTjDe6ZKiiyeWVpdzTwY02W4tuW3i8QPGAVkr1YiYzibWOcSROsc1FEeJJNrsLw4tJ9x7W4RiIBBiD6/oipgOHVE9hy3QVFFnHPKUU3XOi5YYxk0m+QP1IOyJYRkAQQdsCAAgcI90hx2EEH0/VRRdsYI4XNidI0gs6tSROrqlU2hOQvnqHmFaizvematVG0TA7WTznxCH2rmmDHL9VFFrbVkJJoa58nqkneBBjO1kgVNQwk3tBEc1FERbYaVuEHuv1Z7QR3zlwSTWvBaZGwjzUUVW7qwik1yP/9k="

encdoedDataString = encodedDataString.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,","");

byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(encodedDataString.getBytes(), 0);
imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
            imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length));

File photo=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "photo.jpg");

if (photo.exists()) {
    photo.delete();
}

try {
    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(photo.getPath());
    Toast.makeText(this, photo.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    fos.write(imageAsBytes);
    fos.close();
}
catch (java.io.IOException e) {
    Log.e("PictureDemo", "Exception in photoCallback", e);
}
```

hope this will help! cheers!

Comment: sorry, what library used by "Toast" statement